# Cannot load static file in custom nginx error page

Tags: nginx

I have following static files:

```
/home/nginx/js/a.js
/home/nginx/errors/403.html
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
[...]
location / {
    root /home/nginx;
}

error_page 403 /errors/403.html;

location = /errors/403.html {
    root /home/nginx;
}
[...]
```

`403.html` code:

```
[...]
<script src="js/a.js"></script>
[...]
```

However it causes an error, it cannot find wanted `.js` file.
I tried to change it with `../js/a.js`, move `403.html` to root directory (with changes in `nginx.conf's location`) but still no effect. Is it a problem with nginx configuration?

Comment: Have you tried `<script src="/js/a.js"></script>`? Make sure you clear the browser cache between tests.

Comment: Hmm, it worked actually! But it still didn't load it successfully, because of 403 http status code when calling `a.js` file. Ideas? All the files belongs to one user.

Comment: For the 403 error you should post more details about your configuration